# Dynamic form creation from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms

I'm using a 3 nested ng-repeat, for show several questions and her corresponding answers. Untill here is fine, but I must create a form to save the answers, what is the appropiate way to do it? I'm testing with this:

```
<form>
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="section in questionsTest">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1>{{ section.name }}</h1>
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{ section.name }}. {{
                section.description }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="question in section.questions">
            {{ question.statement }}
            <div ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
                <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="{{ answer.type }}" ng-model="test.idRadioButton"
                    name="{{ question.id }}" id="{{ answer.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">
                    {{ answer.valor }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the json:

```
{
    "section": [{
        "name": "Sección 1",
        "questions": [{
            "statement": "Primera pregunta",
            "answers": [{
                "valor": "1",
                "id": 3,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "2",
                "id": 4,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "3",
                "id": 7,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "4",
                "id": 8,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "5",
                "id": 9,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "6",
                "id": 10,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "7",
                "id": 11,
                "type": "radio"
            }],
            "id": 1
        }, {
            "statement": "Pregunta 3",
            "answers": [{
                "valor": "Si",
                "id": 1,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "No",
                "id": 2,
                "type": "radio"
            }],
            "id": 3
        }, {
            "statement": "Pregunta 4",
            "answers": [{
                "valor": "Si",
                "id": 1,
                "type": "radio"
            }, {
                "valor": "No",
                "id": 2,
                "type": "radio"
            }],
            "id": 4
        }],
        "description": "description",
        "id": 1
    }
```

It doesn't work at all, when I click on the first one question all the others questions get clicked also. I'm newbie with angular and I don't know how to face this. Thanks

'Works' now, but I can't store all the radio buttons clicked. This is how I have my controller:

```
$scope.question = {};
    $scope.testing = function(){
        console.log($scope.question);
    };
```

The testing function is just for show the values stored in $scope.question on the console.

Comment: change the id as well, not just name? Also post an example of the json to help decipher your problem

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I've already copied the json and tried changing the id but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different model for each question.

use:

```
ng-model="question.value"
```

I made a working example right here: https://plnkr.co/edit/SMYqvUNqXNJkW9x9ZmsB?p=preview

However maybe you are getting confused with the purpose of the `radio` buttons.  Radio buttons only allow one selected at a time.  If you want more than one you have to set the type to be `checkbox`

Comment: Now is working, I got it like you showed me on plnkr but I can't store the values. I published how I have it on my controller.